# Angular 7 send multiple files to the server

Tags: angular7, asp.net-core-3.0

I have a question about sending a collection of `File` from an Angular 7 application to a .NET Core 3 server.

I have functioning code for sending a single `File` to the server.  But I have hit a problem when I try to send a collection of `File` - i.e: `File[]`.  This is the controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Upload([FromForm(Name = "files")] List<IFormFile> files)
{
      // implementation...
{
```

I send `FormData` in line with code I have used to send a single file to the server:

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('files', this.files);
```

which causes an error with the compiler (see screenshot):

[image]

The FormData cannot deal with the collection of `File[]`.

If I were to change the same code to handle one single File, for example by choosing the first element in the collection, the File is successfully sent to the server.  Like so:

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('files', this.files[0]);
```

The request is sent like this:

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Disposition' : 'multipart/form-data' }),
};

  postPhotos(model: FormData): Observable<any | ErrorReportViewModel> {
    return this.http.post('api/Photograph', model, httpOptions)
    .pipe(
      catchError(error => this.httpErrorHandlerService.handleHttpError(error)));
  }
```

I have also attempted to send the files in the request body with a model.  This does not work: the server receives a `Null` collection of `IFormFile`.  My research suggests that sending FormData is the way to go.  But the FormData seems not to accept the collection of Files.

How can I send the collection of Files to the server?

Comment: Iterate on your files array and add one by one. As you noticed, append accepts only a single file, but can be called multiple times.

Comment: Thank you.  I can do it one at a time.  I'm just going to leave it open in case anyone can suggest a way to send multiple files...

Comment: I'm not suggesting that you need to do multiple requests. You just need to call the append method multiple times in the same request.

Comment: Sorry, I see what you mean... :)

Comment: Check if my answer works.

Comment: It works like this: `this.files.forEach((file) => { formData.append('files', file); });`  Just need to change 'files[]' to 'files'.  I'll update your answer.  Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: Nice. The [] is only for php so. I was not sure

Comment: Thank you again for your help.  That was very helpful. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just need to call append method multiple times:

```
const formData = new FormData();
this.files.forEach((file) => { formData.append('files[]', file); });
```

Wether the key has to be `'files[]'` or can just be `'files'` depends on the serverside platform that parses the body.

Comment: Just a comment: the [] suffix is necessary only for PHP. In Asp.NET it's not needed.

Comment: If you receive a multipartfile like this backend, how can iterate through it?

Comment: Depends on your backend. Most of them will convert it into an array.

Comment: I am unable to catch this with Java, it doesnt get MultipartFile[]. Also, why would you append to 'files[]' every time and not perform a fore each and just append "file"?